# Why doesn't the prefix 'in-' mean the same in "invaluable" and "infamous" as it does in "insufficient" and "incompetent"?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

Looking at a [Prefix/Suffix](http://www.prefixsuffix.com/rootchart.php) chart confirms that the prefix "in-" is *supposed* to mean 'not' or 'without', just wondering why the exception only occurs for certain words. I don't know if it's an origin thing, as infamous originated in Latin, but so did insufficient, and I can't find a concrete orgin of invaluable.

Comment: You should check the etymologies of those words: *infamous* is the opposite of *famous*, which used to simply mean "celebrated"; so the opposite is "not celebrated" (no positive aspect). *Invaluable* means the same thing as *priceless*: not that something has no value (or price) but that it is so valuable one cannot put a price on it (i.e., it cannot be "valued"). Etc.

Comment: Because prefixes don't always mean the same thing. Just like whole words; _bear_ is a verb meaning 'carry', and also a noun referring to an animal, and _bare_ is an adjective meaning 'naked', and we never confuse them in speech. There are at least two _in-_ prefixes. One is the negative one in _insufficient_. The other is the one in _inside_, and it means (surprise) ***in***. That's the one in _infamous_, because it brings someone into fame (that's the etymology; you could look it up). As for _invaluable_, [that's discussed here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: @John, where do you have that etymology for ‘infamous’ from? All Classical Latin senses of words related to _infam-_ refer to ill fame, disrespect, dishonour, etc., clearly the privative prefix, rather than the preverbial preposition. This etymology is also given by etymonline and all other dictionaries I’ve been able to consult here.

Comment: Click on the _in-_ link [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infamis).